# Can main thread end in RESTful webservice while worker thread continues?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I have a Java RESTful webservice that will be called about every 10 seconds by another process.  If conditions are right, the webservice needs to perform a potentially extensive ETL process (say 10 - 20 seconds).  However, we want to return to the calling application right away indicating the payload was delivered successfully to the web service.

Summary of Requirements:

- Validate authentication and input parameters.
- If Validation fails, return error in XML.
- Start thread performing ETL process.  Process will only proceed under certain conditions.
- Return XML indicating payload delivered and validation of input passed.

I have coded this and it appears to run correctly.  But it doesn't seem right.  The thread I created will potentially run longer than the main web service thread.

Anyone want to point me to a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is exactly the right way to do it.  what "doesn't seem right" about the solution?

my only suggestion would be that you shouldn't just launch threads willy-nilly.  you should have some sort of shared ExecutorService managing these ETL process threads.  that will give you visibility into what has been launched and is still running as well as the ability to limit/control the number of background processes (and potentially deal with any rogue executions).

you also might want to generate some sort of "jobId" for the launched process and return that to the caller.  then you could add a call to your api which a client could use to check on the status of a job.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas.  I have implemented an ExecutorService in a singleton.  I'm also using the Callable<> interface on my thread class so I can track the results of the threads and later introduce some code to check for runaway threads.

Answer (score 0):

> ...However, we want to return to the calling application right away
>   indicating the payload was delivered successfully to the web service...

It sounds like you wish to return a success/fail message directly after validation and then again if containing the response of a successful request.

While there is no technical reason this wouldn't work, in typical RESTful web service exchanges there is a one to one HTTP call to request ratio, which this architecture would break by potentially returning two responses for one request. This will probably confuse clients who aren't you or your company.

I might suggest implementing an additional callback service that can be queried asynchronously with a ticket that is returned in the first service request. This has the additional benefit of not blocking service 1  when you're waiting to return the result of your transaction.

Starting up another thread for the transaction is fine as long as your load is low. If it gets too high your requests will start to time out when you can't start any more threads

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can split out the responsibilities of submitting the task and executing the task. You have the submission part down already - your web services receives the request, validates it, but instead of spawning a thread to execute it right away you can save persist it to an external store.

Then have a simple scheduled task (Quartz) running on cron to pick up new tasks and execute them.

The pros to this approach are stronger decoupling and more system flexibility (web service being down doesn't affect task execution and vice versa). The con's are more moving parts (components) in the system.

In any case your current setup works and you are on the right track.